# How to get docker compose to read changes to docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a docker-compose.yml file, and part of it sets up a MySQL docker container.

Below is the part of the file:

```yaml
version: "2.2"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: slurm_acct_db
      MYSQL_USER: slurm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_HOST: "%"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - var_lib_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I can log into the MySQL server from the container with:
`mysql -u slurm -ppassword`

But if I remove the volumes and make changes to the `docker-compose.yml`  e.g. change `MYSQL_PASSWORD` in the `docker-compose.yml` file it doesn't seem to have an effect and the old password is still used.

It is probably very obvious, but I can't seem to find a way for the changes to take effect. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

look to make your compose file appears immediately then you have to run the command:

docker-compose up -d

this will have the update done for you.
or you have another solution that you create another environment variable outside the compose file and then you will need to update the run again to have an effect as it reads the variables immediately from the current file and any effects have to be applied first.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean here, I'm afraid.  I make changes to the `docker-compose.yml`, with the container removed and all volumes deleted, then I start with `docker-compose up -d` but the changes to the `docker-compose.yml` have had no effect.

Comment: no you don't have to delete any thing just editing the variable and executing the command will update the variables not deleting them, because it checks only the changes not and update them.

Comment: well, i might add that if you need me on a live help for free I don't mind and would help any one any time as long as I'm available.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue.

I had started this app using docker-compose in one directory, whilst playing around. I then started the project in a different directory, and docker-compose continued to read the `.yml` file from the first directory, not the current directory I was working in.

Deleted the old directory, and started with `docker-compose up -d` from the second directory I was currently working in, and now the changes have been read.